# Boolean is Giving Unexpected Answer for Python code?

Tags: python

I am not sure what I am doing that is causing this python code to give me a weight answer. Here is my code:

```
x = raw_input("Find Cube Root of A Perfect Cube: ")
root = 3
foo = root * root * root
bar = x
print root * root * root
print x
print (root * root * root) < x

print (foo < bar)
```

These are the print statements given:

27
12
True
True

I understand the first two, of course, but why do I get such an odd answer? 27 is obviously greater than 12.

Comment: I tried your code and got 27, 12, False and False. Maybe you mistyped something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try printing the types of `foo` and `bar`:

```
print type(foo), type(bar)
```

you will get

```
>>> <type 'int'> <type 'str'>
```

**Why you get a string?** Because `raw_input()` returns a string. In Python 2.x, a string will always be greater than an integer, that's why you get that result.

In Python 3.x you will get a `TypeError`:

```
TypeError: unorderable types: int() < str()
```

**How to solve this?** You can convert that string to an integer:

```
x = int(raw_input("Find Cube Root of A Perfect Cube: "))
```

Answer (score 1):

`x` is a `str` object, so `bar` is, too. `foo`, however, is an `int`, and in Python 2.x, any `int` is less than any `str`, because values of unequal types are compared lexicographically by their type name. In Python 3, the comparison would raise an error instead.

Answer (score 1):

`raw_input` returns a string.  You are comparing a string and a number.  Convert `x` to a number with `x = int(x)`.

Answer (score 0):

Cast `x` to an int like this:

```
int(x)
```

That'll give you an integer since `raw_input` returns a string.